# entityManagerFactory bean not configured issue with hibernate 6.0.2.Final and spring boot 2.7.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jakarta-ee

so recently i thought of upgrading few dependency of my spring boot project project
specifically these components

- jakarat ee 9
- spring boot 2.7
- hibernate 6.0.2.Final

after doing this all updates and code refraction: updating imports javax to jakarta, and for few hibernate annotations

I removed the old hibernate from my local .m2 repository and run this command this `mvn clean install test package`

and started the project in intellij and it gave be below error:

```
16:15:42.410 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@429054cc

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.0)

2022-05-30 16:15:42.787  INFO 99522 --- [  restartedMain] com.zee.oms.order.Order                  : Starting Order using Java 17.0.2 on ZL-BLR-MAC170.local with PID 99522 (/Users/manish.prasad/Documents/ZEE-Services/github/zee5-order/target/classes started by manish.prasad in /Users/manish.prasad/Documents/ZEE-Services/github/zee5-order)
2022-05-30 16:15:42.787 DEBUG 99522 --- [  restartedMain] com.zee.oms.order.Order                  : Running with Spring Boot v2.7.0, Spring v5.3.20
2022-05-30 16:15:42.787  INFO 99522 --- [  restartedMain] com.zee.oms.order.Order                  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-05-30 16:15:42.818  INFO 99522 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-05-30 16:15:42.818  INFO 99522 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-05-30 16:15:43.347  INFO 99522 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-05-30 16:15:43.433  INFO 99522 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 81 ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-05-30 16:15:43.862  INFO 99522 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-05-30 16:15:43.868  INFO 99522 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-05-30 16:15:43.868  INFO 99522 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.63]
2022-05-30 16:15:43.902  INFO 99522 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/order-srv]     : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-05-30 16:15:43.902  INFO 99522 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1084 ms
2022-05-30 16:15:44.059  WARN 99522 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'orderController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'orderService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'orderServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'orderRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orderRepository' defined in com.zee.oms.order.repository.OrderRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#14203bc' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#14203bc': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
2022-05-30 16:15:44.061  INFO 99522 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-05-30 16:15:44.072  INFO 99522 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-05-30 16:15:44.080 ERROR 99522 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field orderRepository in com.oms.order.service.impl.OrderServiceImpl required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 0
```

this is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.zee</groupId>
    <artifactId>zee5-order</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>order</name>
    <description>Spring Boot project for order-service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <hibernate.version>6.0.2.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.common-utility</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-utility</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.220</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.212</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-60</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

attaching few screen shots for the added dependencies:

[spring and spring boot dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WTVn.jpg)

[jakarta dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okR5w.png)

any idea or solution if anybody have also upgraded to this version and able to run the project successfully.
also iam confused why javax-persistence is still there and not replaced when jakarata-persistence is already added/there.

Comment: HIbernate 6 is a JakartaEE implementation, Spirng BOot doesn't support that (yet). Remove the `hibernate.version` property as well as the `validation` dependencies (add `spring-boot-starter-validation instead) as those are for JakartaEE as well.

Comment: A bit beside the question but `mvn clean install` will run test and package so you don't need to add them to the list.

Comment: @M.Deinum so does that mean i cannot use the latest hibernate with spring boot 2.7 :(. if yes then isnt it a bit awkward that why the latest spring boot stable version(released recently) is not having the jakarta ee 9 and hibernate 6 dependencies inbuilt

Comment: Because that is a breaking change and that is left for a major release (Spring Boot 3, with Spring 6 which also would need to change). It isn't only hibernate that would need to change but everything that used JavaEE needs to change to JakartaEE including other libraries. It isn't an option to support both at the same time.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you so much for giving this understanding. Iam pretty much clear now and rolling back the changes as you suggested and will wait for the major spring boot release (v3). Also if you you want can post the above comment as answer and i would love to mark it accepted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate 6 (and Hibernate Validator 7 as well) are JakartaEE implementations of respectivly the Jakarta Persistence API and Jakarta Validation API. None of which are currently supported by Spring nor Spring Boot.

Support for JakartaEE is coming in Spring Framework 6 and Spring Boot 3 which are scheduled for release later this year.

For now keep using the JavaEE versions. In your case you need to do 2 things

1. Remove the `hibernate.version` property
2. Replace the `hibernate-validator` and `jakarta-validation-api` with the `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency.

When you apply both fixes and later this year upgrade to Spring Boot 3 you will get the proper versions which are compatible.

Comment: applied the above changes and left spring boot version to 2.7. things are working fine now. will wait for the v3 release.

Comment: How to use spring-boot 2.7.0 with hibernate-core 6.1.1.Final since h2 database need  this hibernate version to work with Oracle `OFFSET` / `FETCH`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72932843/jparepository-oracle-pagination-limit-and-offset?noredirect=1#comment128818036_72932843 @manish